# How do I check for the existence of an external file with XSL?

Tags: xslt, document, external, xsl-fo, exists

I've found a lot of examples that reference Java and C for this, but how do I, or can I, check for the existence of an external file with XSL.

First, I realize that this is only a snippet, but it's part of a huge stylesheet, so I'm hoping it's enough to show my issue.

```
    <!-- Use this template for Received SMSs -->
<xsl:template name="ReceivedSMS">
    <!-- Set/Declare "SMSname" variable (local, evaluates per instance) -->
    <xsl:variable name="SMSname">
        <xsl:value-of select=" following-sibling::Name"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <fo:table font-family="Arial Unicode MS" font-size="8pt" text-align="start">
        <fo:table-column column-width=".75in"/>
        <fo:table-column column-width="6.75in"/>
        <fo:table-body>
            <fo:table-row>
                <!-- Cell contains "speakers" icon -->
                <fo:table-cell display-align="after">
                    <fo:block text-align="start">
                        <fo:external-graphic src="../images/{$SMSname}.jpg" content-height="0.6in"/>
```

What I'd like to do, is put in an "if" statement, surronding the `{$SMSname}.jpg` line.  That is:

```
                     <fo:block text-align="start">
                        <xsl:if test="exists( the external file {$SMSname}.jpg)">
                            <fo:external-graphic src="../images/{$SMSname}.jpg" content-height="0.6in"/>                            
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="not(exists( the external file {$SMSname}.jpg))">
                            <fo:external-graphic src="../images/unknown.jpg" content-height="0.6in"/>                            
                        </xsl:if>
                    </fo:block>
```

Because of "grouping", etc., I'm using XSLT 2.0.  I hope that this is something that can be done.  I hope even more that it's something simple.

As always, thanks in advance for any help.
LO

Comment: Good question (+1). Short answer: cannot be currently done with pure XSLT 2.0. Long answer and explanation: see my answer. :)

Comment: It looks like it will be possible with EXPath extensions - file package (http://expath.org/spec/file)...

Comment: I have done it for myself, Check my answer for the solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No, this cannot be done using XSLT 2.0/XPath 2.0.**

The XSLT 2.0 function **[unparsed-text-available()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-unparsed-text-available)** is only suitable for locating text files and even if a text file with the specifies URI exists this function may return false(), because it also must read the contents of the file and check that it only contains allowed characters.

**From the** **[spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-unparsed-text-available)**:

"The unparsed-text-available function determines whether a call on the unparsed-text function with identical arguments would return a string.

If the first argument is an empty sequence, the function returns false. If the second argument is an empty sequence, the function behaves as if the second argument were omitted.

In other cases, the function returns true if a call on unparsed-text with the same arguments would succeed, and false if a call on unparsed-text with the same arguments would fail with a non-recoverable dynamic error.

Note:

This requires that the unparsed-text-available function should actually attempt to read the resource identified by the URI, and check that it is correctly encoded and contains no characters that are invalid in XML
"

**End of quotation.**

Answer (score 12):

For anyone else who might stumble upon this old question, by piecing together information from various sources on the internet, I came up with this XSLT2 function that uses a Java extension for checking whether a file exists:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:java="http://www.java.com/"
  exclude-result-prefixes="java xs">

  <xsl:function name="java:file-exists" xmlns:file="java.io.File" as="xs:boolean">
    <xsl:param name="file" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:param name="base-uri" as="xs:string"/>

    <xsl:variable name="absolute-uri" select="resolve-uri($file, $base-uri)" as="xs:anyURI"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="file:exists(file:new($absolute-uri))"/>
  </xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can then use the function like this:

```
<xsl:if test="java:file-exists($filename, base-uri())">
  <!-- ... -->
</xsl:if>
```

This works at least with Saxon 9.1.0.5J — haven't tested it with any other XSLT processors.

**Note**: If the file for whose existence you're checking is an XML file and you're using XSLT2, you can also use the built-in `doc-available()` function:

```
<xsl:if test="doc-available('hello_world.xml')">
  <!-- ... -->
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: With PE9.4, I get the error message `Error at xsl:sequence on line 32 column 66 of propertize-opf.xslt:
  XPST0017 XPath syntax error at char 12 on line 32 near {...xists(file:new($absolute-ur...}:
    Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named {java.io.File}new(). For diagnostics on calls to Java methods, use the -TJ command line option or set the Configuration property FeatureKeys.TRACE_EXTERNAL_FUNCTIONS`

Comment: @torazaburo: Are you sure you're passing `base-uri()` as the second argument to `java:file-exists()`? As in: `<xsl:if test="java:file-exists($filename, base-uri())"> <!-- ... ---> </xsl:if>`. Also, note that this function will only work on XSLT2.0.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone else needs it and is using fop, I would like to share [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20246027/2796922) since it worked for me like a charm.

I've found a solution:

```
<xsl:when test="fs:exists(fs:new('myfile.html'))" xmlns:fs="java.io.File">
    <!-- do something here... -->
</xsl:when>
```

and it works independently of XSLT 1.0 or 2.0

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Use [unparsed-text-available function](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XSL-Ref/Tutorials/Multiple-Source-Documents/msd4.html). It is part of [xslt 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-unparsed-text-available), but not XQuery or standalone XPath.

I've left my previous answer here so you can follow the trail of uncertainty...

I don't believe there is a way of doing this in XSLT using the standard functions. You can do it using extension functions, as described [here](http://www.biglist.com/lists/xsl-list/archives/200506/msg00400.html), for java.

There is the [unparsed-text-available](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_unparsed-text-available.html) function, but I'm unsure if this is a standard function. There's an example of it's usage at [Zvon](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XSL-Ref/Tutorials/Multiple-Source-Documents/msd4.html). The unparsed-text-available is mentioned [here](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2007/03/21/the-future-of-xslt-20.html) as being part of xslt 2.0, and is supported in Saxon.

Answer (score 2):

A proposed [File Module EXPath specification](http://expath.org/spec/file) would support file-system functions such as this (`file:exists()` in the spec) as standard XPath extension functions. There isn't yet an XSLT implementation for this, but its worth watching.

Comment: This is not working for me below is error:
XPath syntax error at char 30 on line 40 in {...file:exists($htmlFilePath))...}:
    Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named {http://expath.org/ns/file}exists()

Comment: Is it dependent on saxon version I am using saxon 8 but don't think that would be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Back to pgfearo's notice.

> A proposed File Module EXPath specification would support file-system
>   functions such as this (file:exists() in the spec) as standard XPath
>   extension functions. There isn't yet an XSLT implementation for this,
>   but its worth watching.

For those who need to check if an file exists or not.

```
file:exists($path as xs:string)
```

works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

If you still wants to do it in XSLT here is the solution, I have done it for myself as explained below.

This will not working with regular **java.io.File** class in XSLT. So I have used **java.nio.file.Files** class.

JARS required - servelt.jar
w: is the namespace of the our own Java class where pathFromURI method is defined.

Code:

```
<xsl:variable name="fileURI" select="u:new($absoluteFilePath)" xmlns:u="java:java.net.URI"/>
<xsl:variable name="filePathFromURI" select="w:pathFromURI($fileURI)"/>
<xsl:variable name="fileNotExist" select="not(files:exists($filePathFromURI, /..)) or files:size($filePathFromURI) = 0"/>

public static java.nio.file.Path pathFromURI(java.net.URI uri) throws Exception {
    return java.nio.file.Paths.get(uri);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't solely be done by standard XSLT, you have to use an extention function or some annoying workaround. There are two methods using extension functions: use of standard java/.NET for custom functions (works with some versions of Saxon, AltovaXML, and others), or use of processor specific extension functions, like saxon:file-last-modified()/[saxon:last-modified()](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.2/extensions/functions/last-modified.html). You can find some sample code [here](http://code.google.com/p/xslt-sb/source/browse/trunk/xslt-sb/files.xsl), look for intern:file-exists().

If you can't use extension functions, you can either generate an XML file externaly which contains informations about your file system and pass it to your stylesheet, or you can wrap binary images within SVG and than use fn:doc-available().

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check for the existence of an XML file, use an external entity and an inline doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE foo [ <!ENTITY bar SYSTEM "baz.xml"> ]>
```

Then add the entity to the stylesheet:

```
&bar;
```

The processor will timeout if the file is not found.

If you know the files exist but want to dynamically load one out of many, use the `concat` function and a `choose/when` block:

```
<xsl:variable name="page_name">
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$page = 1">
    <xsl:value-of select="'page1.xml'"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="$page = 2">
    <xsl:value-of select="'page2.xml'"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <!--...-->
  <xsl:when test="$page = 9">
    <xsl:value-of select="'page9.xml'"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="$page = 10">
    <xsl:value-of select="'page10.xml'"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="'page0.xml'"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="agree" select="document(concat('include/pages/',$page_name))//processing-instruction()"/>
```

**References**

- [XML External Entity (XXE) Processing](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XXE)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who needs plain XSLT solution for checking if file exist you can just use

```
unparsed-text-available(concat(system-property('user.dir'),'/filename.text'))
```

or wrap it into a function

```
<xsl:function name="functx:file-exists" xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com">
    <xsl:param name="path"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="unparsed-text-available(concat(system-property('user.dir'),'/',$path))"/>
</xsl:function>
```

using this `unparsed-text-available(concat(system-property('user.dir'),'/filename.text'))=false()` will mean that file does not exist.

Have fun!